# What factors to consider for choosing a MSc program in Computer Science for someone who wants to get a Ph.D. position later?

Tags: phd, masters, computer-science

I am interested in pursuing a Ph.D. program after completing my Masters. How can I compare different Master's programs in Computer Science based on my long-term goal and choose one? Should I check a specific ranking or ...

When I search the internet about how to choose a Master's program, most people talk about salaries or finding a job after graduation, but that is not my intention and I am interested in getting a good Ph.D. position after graduation.

Comment: Why do you want to do another MSc in CS?

Comment: @user151413 I don't. It's going to be my first MSc. Currently, I have a BSc in Computer Engineering.

Comment: We don't allow [shopping questions](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping) that compare or rank programs/journals/fields, etc, and a question of "where should I go" also [depends on individual factors](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-depending-on-individual-factors). Your title, though, is okay, but I fear that the details about particular programs in the body dodges the rules a bit and may invite answerers to answer the against-policy part of the question.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks for telling me. I didn't know. I edited the body of my question. Can you please read it once again and tell me if it is ok now.

Comment: Yes, thank you; you could consider adding some of the other details of parameters you're considering if you keep them vague (if you'd like those points specifically addressed in an answer, that is). It's possible someone else has already asked a similar enough question that people will vote to close as a duplicate, but I think with these edits you escape the shopping/individual factors close reasons.

Comment: Is this for the case that you already have a specific area of research that you are interested in? If yes, you can have a look which researchers are at the universities under consideration and see which direction you are more interested in. Otherwise, it's a bit more difficult.

Comment: @SMMousaviSP Sorry, I misread. Regarding your original question, I would vouch for the program with a longer master thesis, especially if you want to do a PhD in a place where this is also common (like ETH). Maybe this is my German perspective, but I feel that after a long (often 9-12 month) thesis one can judge people's research abilities much better. (Note that the 30 ECTS are not always the full truth, and the thesis is in fact longer, with the credits split between the thesis and some "master seminar" or the like.)

Comment: @user151413 Thank you. Unfortunately, some universities in Germany make admission decisions in mid-July. If I wait until then and don't get admission, I will also lose the admissions I already have. One thing that I always hear about German universities is that they primarily only care about your GPA. Is that true? I have a good resume, my GPA is 17.84 / 20, and my last 2 years' GPA is 19.01 / 20, and I ranked 1st. IELTS 8.0, good recoms and several projects in the area I'm interested in. But I must mention I studied at a 1200+ rank university and no papers. Do you see me as a good candidate?

Comment: I have no idea about admission in CS. But generally in Germany admission for BSc/MSc goes by grade, which is converted according to some standardized schemes for applicants with a degree from abroad. Those schemes are university-dependent (the one where you got your degree from!), so you might try to figure out the conversion rule.